# How do I test this Sinatra Method?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Trivial Sinatra application:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'haml'

class InfoController < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

And my test:

```
describe InfoController do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    InfoController
  end

  it "should return the index page when visiting the root of the site" do    
    get '/'
    last_response.should be_ok
  end
end
```

But I do not want to test whether or not the haml method worked, I just want to test that the index view was rendered.

How would you test that?  Redefine the `haml` method?  Mock the `haml` method somehow?

Comment: You said that you don't want to test whether or not the haml method worked, but want to test that the index view was rendered — it's the same thing bacause if haml method failed index view render will fail too, also ok? method tests only for 200 status code

Answer (score -1):

What about testing the actual markup that was rendered?

last_response.body.should match(/your text/)